# How to find the 'parent' of 'this' Node?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

When targeting the current node, you can do `event="function(this)"` to tell the function you are dealing with this node. How can you get the node that the current element is in?

```
<div>
    <span event="function(this)">Click here</span>
</div>
```

I want to deal with the `div`, not the `span`. The current code deals with the `span`.

Comment: [`this.parentNode`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-1060184317).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each DOM Node has a [`parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.parentNode) property for that.